# Referring an active cell in a worksheet to another worksheet

Tags: excel, excel-2010, worksheet-function, worksheet

I have a worksheet (let me call it WorksheetA) that each row has a different information. Then, I want to refer these information (per row) on my other worksheet (WorksheetB).

To explain further, WorksheetA has 2 columns that should be copied to WorksheetB. These are "Name" and "School Last Attended". I want to know how can WorksheetB be updated every time a new row in WorksheetA is filled. Also, there will only be one cell on WorksheetB to hold values for the column "Name" from WorksheetA and another one cell (WorksheetB) for column "School Last Attended" from WorksheetA.

It will be really helpful if the answer to this question is within the environment of Excel, that I won't have to require any other software/program.

Thanks in advance!! :)

Answer (score 0):

OK I may may not have interpreted this correctly but here goes.

In Sheet1 (your Worksheet A) we have two columns of data which are updated by adding to the end of the list:

[image: Sheet1 Layout]

In Sheet2 (your Worksheet B) there are two cells (B4 and D4 in this example) that hold and will continually update with the LAST details held in the Sheet1 list.

[image: Sheet2 Layout]

To achieve this ON:

SHEET2 in cell B4 enter: **=INDIRECT("'" & B1 & "'!B" &  COUNTA(Sheet1!B:B))**

SHEET2 in cell D4 enter: **=OFFSET(INDIRECT("'" & B1 & "'!B" &  COUNTA(Sheet1!B:B)),0,1)**

Edit (in hindsight)

Note that you must include the name of the data worksheet in cell B1 of sheet2 - this is required for the INDIRECT function to operate across sheets.

Note also that there should be no blank rows in the block of data in Sheet1 - this is because the last data value in col B is being found using COUNTA